# Modify introductory regular expression

Tags: regex

Here is a regular expression -

`/\/./`

So for

`String = "c:\test/test/a.txt"`

"/t" is matched.

How can I amend the expression to match the char to the right of the last forward slash only?
So

`"c:\test/test/a.txt"`

becomes "a" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(.)(?!.*/)
```

Use negative lookahead ansertion. This means to match `/.` only when there is no other `/` following. Group 1 has the first character after the last `/`

Comment: The regular expression returns the / character also but I just remove it programatically

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
/\/([^/])+$/
```

Which basically means:

Match a slash character followed by a non-slash (captured) followed by 0 or more non-slash characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
/.*\/(.)/
```